# Adding Custom Protocol in Registry Editor for MikroTik Winbox

Tags: java, php, c++, registry, protocols

I have a small windows application called Winbox (It's a tiny application to control RouterBoard).
We are making a web application which needed to make a custom protocol URL like :

```
oxo://192.168.103.3 {USERNAME} {PASSWORD}
```

I just need the oxo:// to be pointed to [c:/winbox.exe] and execute the application with the arguments {IP ADDRESS} {USERNAME} {PASSWORD}

So i have edited a registry editor code :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\oxo]
@="\"URL:oxo Protocol\""
"EditFlags"=hex:02,00,00,00
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\oxo\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\winbox.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\oxo\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\oxo\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\oxo\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\winbox.exe\" \"%1\""
```

But the problem is when opening the url in browser it will display the "oxo://{IP ADDRESS}" in the {IP ADDRESS} field.
Which is not working

All i need is to remove the first part of the protocol name "oxo://" from the final executable path

If you want to download Winbox.exe:
http://download2.mikrotik.com/winbox.exe

Usage :

```
winbox.exe {IP ADDRESS} {USERNAME} {PASSWORD}
```

---

```
{IP ADDRESS} : Is the IP Address of the remote RouterBaord device.
{USERNAME} : Is the username of the RouterBoard Device.
{PASSWORD} : Is the password of the RouterBoard Device.
```

Please i need any help with this problem even if it's in JAVA, C, C++ or any programming language.

I just want to run the exe file with arguments from web browser.

Many Thanks,
Areeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your links contain dynamic Arguments,
the key is to make oxo is to open Console Application
and you can use this code for your console application to redirect your application to winbox.exe

```
 Sub Main()
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim url As String = Command()
        url = url.Replace("/", "")
        url = url.Replace("oxo", "")
        url = url.Replace(":", "")
        Dim arg() As String = url.Split(",")
        Dim IP As String = arg(2)
        Dim Username As String = arg(1)
        Dim Password As String = arg(0)
        Shell("c:\winbox\winbox.exe " & IP & " " & Username & " " & Password)
        Console.WriteLine("Yout username : " & Username & " Password : " & Password & " Ip : " & IP)
    End Sub
```

and your links would be

```
oxo://{PASSWORD},{USERNAME},{IP}
```